# Is there any function in OpenNLP that perform semantic analysis between sentences?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, opennlp

I want to check how a sentence is similar to other, on the basis of semantic relation between them. Is there any function in OpenNLP to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of "semantic" are you thinking of? Can you give an example?

Comment: for instance if i ask "how are you " then it will match this string using that specific function, with  all the possible strings (stored in a list) and return one with highest possiblity

Comment: i guess there is a synset funtion but i don't know how to use it. Also please help me if you know how to access Wnlib ? it might solve my issue

Comment: I cannot see how synsets would help. Consider the sentences "how are you", "how you're doing" and "good evening". Single word synonyms will not help you to establish any kind of similarity. Never heard about "Wnlib".